# Not an managed type: class entity. & Spring Data

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I'm working with `spring data`, i create config class with `@Bean`, `@Entity` and `Main.java` but when run project i get exception:

`Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'todoRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class entity.Todo`

My **Main.java**

```
    public class Main {

    @Autowired
    private static TodoRepository todoRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Todo todo = new Todo();
        todo.setId(1l);
        todo.setTitle("title");
        System.out.println(todoRepository); //null
        todoRepository.save(todo);          //Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    }
}
```

**PersistenceContext.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"repository"},
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
public class PersistenceContext {

    public PersistenceContext() {
    }

    /**
     * The method that configures the datasource bean
     * */

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    DataSource dataSource() {
        HikariConfig dataSourceConfig = new HikariConfig();
        dataSourceConfig.setJdbcUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("db.url"));
        dataSourceConfig.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty("db.driver"));
        dataSourceConfig.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("db.username"));
        dataSourceConfig.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("db.password"));
        return new HikariDataSource(dataSourceConfig);
    }

    /**
     * The method that configures the entity manager factory
     * */
    @Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, Environment env) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("net.petrikainulainen.springdata.jpa.todo");

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();

        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    /**
     * The method that configures the transaction manager
     * */
    @Bean
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

**Todo.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "todos")
public class Todo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "title", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String title;

    public Todo() {
    }
    //getter setter tostring
}
```

*All stacktrace:*

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
сен 02, 2015 2:54:49 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
sep 02, 2015 2:54:49 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.0.Final}
sep 02, 2015 2:54:49 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
sep 02, 2015 2:54:49 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
sep 02, 2015 2:54:49 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.0.Final}
sep 02, 2015 2:54:49 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
sep 02, 2015 2:54:50 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
sep 02, 2015 2:54:50 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'todoRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class entity.Todo
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1554)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
    at Main.main(Main.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class entity.Todo
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:210)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:68)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:67)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:146)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:90)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:70)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:171)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:239)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:225)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1613)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1550)
    ... 16 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your Todo class name, as shown by the error message, is `entity.Todo`. So it's in the package `entity`.

But your entity manager factory is configured this way:

```
entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("net.petrikainulainen.springdata.jpa.todo");
```

So your `entity` package is not scanned, and the `Todo` entity is thus unknown to JPA.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. Maybe you know why I have an error when I use `@Autowired` *(delete `ApplicationContext`)* i get exception  `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException` in line `todoRepository.save(todo);`

Comment: You didn't post any line of code of the TodoRepository. If this answer solved your problem, you should accept it by ticking the grey mark next to the question. If you're stuck with the other problem, ask *another* question, with the relevant code.

Comment: Okey, i create new question!

Answer (score 6):

For Spring boot you must define entitymanager.packagesToScan properties in application.properties like below;

entitymanager.packagesToScan = com.app.domain

Answer (score 0):

While dealing with hibernate always check package scan under `repositories` and  `entityManagerFactory` along with `<context:component-scan base-package="com.company"/>`

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.company" />
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" id="mysql_dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="${database.connectionPool.testOnBorrow}" />
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="${database.connectionPool.testOnReturn}" />
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="${database.connectionPool.testWhileIdle}" />
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="${database.connectionPool.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis}" />
    <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="${database.connectionPool.numTestsPerEvictionRun}" />
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="${database.connectionPool.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis}" />
    <property name="maxWait" value="${database.connectionPool.maxWait}"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="${database.connectionPool.maxActive}"/>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="${database.connectionPool.maxIdle}"/>
    <property name="minIdle" value="${database.connectionPool.minIdle}"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="${database.connectionPool.initialSize}"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="${database.connectionPool.validationQuery}" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.company</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mysql_dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.archive.autodetection">class,hbm</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

If You are using eclipse IDE click on run configuration and Make sure Resolve Workspace artifact checkbox is selected. It works for me [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHE9X.png)